# Is there a way to grant access to gcloud using only information in the JSON key file but not the JSON file itself (on Colab)?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-colaboratory

To grant access to Google cloud services without google account, a json key file is needed in the following way:

```
!gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file xxx.json
```

But if the user do not have the json file, what information in the json file could I provide for the user to access the cloud service? Is this even possible? I am using google colab.

Many Thanks!

Comment: To use a service account, the user needs a service account JSON key file. Edit your question to better explain your problem and what you are trying to solve. There are advanced methods such as using a user identity that impersonates a service account. If your goal is to keep some information private by just providing part of the JSON key file, you can't. The CLI (gcloud) needs that information to use a service account.

Comment: @JohnHanley ok got it. Thanks. Another question: on colab, is is possible to directly place the entire json key directly inside the code, and then authenticate using the code above?

Comment: If you have a new question create a new post. I do not use colab, but if you mean to use a service account json file to authorize code, yes. I recommend reading documentation on authorization for Python. There are countless example on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Posting @John Hanley's answer in the comment section as a Community wiki answer:

To use a service account, the user needs a service account JSON key file. Advanced methods such as using a `user identity` that impersonates a service account. If your goal is to keep some information private by just providing part of the JSON key file, you can't. The CLI (gcloud) needs that information to use a service account.